# tramp-mode popping up while editing c/c++ files

Tags: tramp

recently, some strange behaviour popped up when editing c/c++ files in emacs: Whenever I want to write a comment, the first `/` I enter will open a buffer of type `*tramp/spc C*` with error message

> ssh: could not resolve hostname c: Name or service not known

My research has brought me as far as finding out that this is related to tramp-mode, something I never used or even knew that it exists. So, my question is: How can I get rid of this behaviour?

Using emacs24, installed from the Ubuntu 16.04 repos, if that matters.

Thanks for any advice.

**EDIT 16/12/16**

this most have something to do with my `.emacs` as the buffer is not popping up when starting with `emacs -q`.

Active modes in my editing buffer are

Abbrev Auto-Complete Auto-Composition Auto-Compression Auto-Encryption Blink-Cursor Electric-Indent File-Name-Shadow Font-Lock Global-Auto-Complete Global-Font-Lock Line-Number Menu-Bar Mouse-Wheel Tool-Bar Tooltip Transient-Mark

Comment: Maybe you get some insight with `describe-mode` (C-h m), which gives you a list of enabled minor modes for the buffer. Or at least add this list of modes to your question so others can help.

Comment: Does this happen if you run a clean emacs (with `emacs -q`)?

Comment: No, it does not happen with `emacs -q` - edited the original question to contain the output of `describe-mode`.

Answer (score 0):

See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/778716/how-can-i-make-emacs-start-up-faster
for similar problem(s), you need to solve for hostname, by editing /etc/hostname, and /etc/hostsfile. (see the answer of tsar2512).

Another solution (worked for me, on my mac): edit ~/.ssh/config file, replace everything you find out there with the following:

```
Host *
ControlPath ~/.ssh/master-%r@%h:%p
ControlMaster auto
```